# Should I do my task quickly or should I take lot of time to complete?

Tags: software-industry, manager, productivity, task-management, quality

When I am assigned a task by my manager.I usually take a lot of time to finish and sometimes I complete it in 1 or 2 days. I feel that if I do fast they think that I did without quality and if take time they think I'm inefficient. What qualities does management appreciate.....fast work with low quality or slow delayed work with high quality. What is a good approach.

Consider I have to create a technical document and management has not given any deadline. Now, I can take weeks and delay it or finish it in one day.

I work as a IT professional in software industry. I have 5 years of experience.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without context other than saying as quickly as possible in order to get the level of quality your manager wants.  If you're writing software that runs a passenger plane's autopilot system, your organization probably puts a bit more emphasis on quality than it would if you were writing a Facebook clone.

Answer (score 6):

You are presenting a false choice: it is not true that either you do something dirty and quick or clean and slow. There are many degrees between the two.

What's expected is that you spend an adequate amount of time for each task and show good judgement in balancing quality and effort depending on the circumstances.

If you are in doubt, you can ask your manager for more specifics or simply look at what your colleagues do in similar cases.

Answer (score 2):

Management generally appreciate it if tasks are completed within whatever timeframe they gave you and with no errors. Judging by your question you rush things and numerous errors creep in. This would not be a good sign to management.

Efficient, professional, error free work is most appreciated. I have seen many rushed jobs full of errors, and many slowly taken jobs full of errors.